# Problem with missing property in lib.dom.d.ts file when update to latest typescript version

Tags: angular, typescript

I have upgraded my Angular project to latest version following official upgrade manual from [here](https://update.angular.io/). When I run 'ng serve' in the project folder I get error

```
"ERROR in src/app/menu/menu-tree.component.ts(93,63): error TS2339: Property 'localName' does not exist on type 'Node'.
```

I have found the definition of the Node type in the lib.dom.d.ts (full path: C:\Users\my_user\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\extensions\node_modules\typescript\lib\lib.dom.d.ts).

Here is affected code:

```js
if ( mutation.type === 'childList' && mutation.target.localName === 'span' &&
          mutation.addedNodes.length > 0 && mutation.removedNodes.length === 0) {
```

Definition of property 'target' in the interface MutationRecord in lib.dom.d.ts:

```js
readonly target: Node;
```

Comment: What typescript version was installed? What version were you going from/to?

Comment: Actual version: 3.2.4. Before upgrade it was probably 2.5.3 ("~2.5.3" in package.json).

Comment: There's also this https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/localName

Comment: Thank you @OneLunchMan. I have been looking for any references to the 'localName' property.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not use `mutation.target.nodeName.toLowerCase() === 'span'`?